# Where to save custom Laravel filters?

Tags: php, filter, laravel, laravel-4

I have been searching for an answer for a while now with no clear results. I know that you can save your custom filters in the 'app/filters.php' file but it doesn't look so great if you're trying to keep your code base clean enough.

Let's say I'm writing a small (but hopefully efficient) roles based auth system for my app
is there any path I should consider "official" to create this filters file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you'll see the Laravel Core Developers say a lot: there's no such thing like a right place for your files in Laravel. It all depends on your project design and the way you work.

In Taylor`s first book (https://leanpub.com/laravel) he says: "Is your models directory deleted yet? If not, get it out of there!". If a directory that 'important' can be deleted and files moved away, anything else can go away too, as long your application benefits from it.

A start (good for me, maybe not for you): create an `app/services/<ServiceName>` directory and put the related filters.php (by service) there. And then load them as Laravel do with its own filters.php, via globals.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Require The Filters File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will load the filters file for the application. This gives us
| a nice separate location to store our route and application filter
| definitions instead of putting them all in the main routes file.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../filters.php';
```

At some point you might need to load them differently, maybe doing it on the boot() method of service providers...